# Closed form for $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{\ln(n)}=?$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I try to find the sum of this alternating series : $\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{\ln(n)}$.

Since $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{\ln(n)}=0$ and $\{\frac{1}{\ln(n)}\}$ is a decreasing sequence then by Alternating Series Test we know $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{\ln(n)}$ is convergent.

Any hint or idea about how to find a closed form formula for the sum of this series ?

Comment: thanks,can you explain more about what the the closed for this series?

Comment: I don’t believe it has a closed form. This is just speculation on my part and I don’t have a good reason to back this up though except this: if it had a closed form then I think it would be a famous result since the summand is such a nice and simple function. I've been around the block when it comes to sums and integrals and I have not heard about it. I can make this claim a bit more objective by computing the sum and using the inverse symbolic calculator. It finds no matches.

Comment: Mathematica 11 can't do it.

Comment: btw what you can do is to rewrite the sum as an integral: $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\log(n)} = \int_0^\infty [1-\left(1-2^{1-x}\right) \zeta (x)]{\rm d}x$$ where $\zeta(s)$ is the Riemann zeta function.

Comment: $(\ln \ln x)' = \frac{1}{x \ln x}$, and $\sum_{n=2}^\infty (\ln \ln n) (-1)^n n^{-s}$ is maybe less hard

Comment: @Winther: how did you get that result?  Sure looks tricky.

Comment: @RonGordon btw [you should know this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/476526/147873) :)